# Keep most frequent value per group

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to summarise some data.frame containing both numeric and character values. I need to sum the numerical features and to keep the most frequent character value per group at the same time. Ideally, it should be with *dplyr* but that's not mandatory.

Here is a reproducible example :

```
have <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),"a" = c("dog","dog","cat","duck","duck","horse"),"value" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
need <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2), "a" = c("dog","duck"), "value" = c(6,15))
```

Any idea ?

Comment: While @Quiten's answer is totally valid and probably the way to go here, you might wanna check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2547402/13460602 where they discuss how to find the statistical mode (i.e. the most frequent value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `group_by` and `sum` for total value and use `table` with `which.max` and `names` to select the character values that frequent the most like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
have %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(a = names(which.max(table(a))),
            value = sum(value))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      id a     value
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 dog       6
#> 2     2 duck     15
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `collapse::fmode` which is probably the fastest way of finding the statistical mode:

```r
library(dplyr) 
have %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(a = collapse::fmode(a),
            value = sum(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      id a     value
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 dog       6
#> 2     2 duck     15
```

Answer (score 3):

Here we first count and then apply the max a to all other and finally summarise:

```
library(dplyr) # dplyr >= 1.1.0

have %>% 
  add_count(id, a) %>% 
  mutate(a = first(a), .by=id) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value), .by=c(id, a))
 
  id    a value
1  1  dog     6
2  2 duck    15
```